# How to setup an Autoconf project to make with GTK?

Tags: c, gcc, gtk, configure, autoconf

how to setup my autoconf project to use GTK? There is only one source file (main.c). I already created all necessary files for autoconf, and when I type "make" it can't find the GTK include "gtk/gtk.h".

// make error

> make[2]: Entering directory `/home/anon/projects/firstgtkprog/src' gcc
>   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c main.c:1:21: fatal error:
>   gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

// configure.ac file contents

> AC_INIT([firstgtkprog], [1.0], [bug-developer@foda.com])
>
> AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
>
> AC_PROG_CC
>
> AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
>
> AC_CONFIG_FILES([  Makefile  src/Makefile ])
>
> AC_OUTPUT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GTK+ uses the `pkg-config` utility to provide the necessary compiler and library flags to development tools that build programs with the library. For example, `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` prints out the flags to compile with GTK, and `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` prints out the libs.

To integrate this with the Autoconf build system, you need to use the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro. [This tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/anjuta-build-tutorial/stable/library-autotools.html.en) explains it in some details.